# Multiply matrix and polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

can I get an example for multiplying a general matrix (in my case a representative matrix for linear transformation) with a general polynomial in degree 2.

I couldn't figure out how to represent the polynomial ($a + bx + cx^2$) in a vector.
(Couldn't find examples on the web) thanks!

Comment: Represent $a+bx+cx^2\in K[x]$ by the vector $(a,b,c)\in K^3$.

Comment: What does $K$ mean here?